# Force init in Gitea when repo is created

Tags: gitea

When you create a repo in Gitea from the website you can mark "*Initialize Repository (Adds .gitignore, License and README)*", and when you create a repo in Gitea from the [API](https://servicio.mapa.gob.es/git/api/swagger#/organization/createOrgRepo) you can set `auto_init` to *true*.

Is there any way to configure Gitea to force *Initialize Repository* for all repos no matter if they are created from the website or API and no matter what the user chose for this option?

In other words, I need to configure my Gitea to always initialize every repo that is created.